# How to set and change value of constant variable/ struct/pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

In .h file

```
typedef enum
{A1,A2}struct_A;

typedef struct
{const struct_A G;} struct_B;

typedef struct
{const struct_B * F;} struct_C;

typedef struct
{const struct_C *E;} struct_D;
```

In .c file

```
const struct_D temp;
```

How to set/change value of:

```
temp->E[i].F[0].G
```

Comment: Please make sure you spot auto-capitalization and fix it — cell phones are a menace for typing code on SO.  The use of `Typedef` and `Const` is careless, ultimately, and programmers cannot afford to be careless.

Comment: You need to initialize `temp` when it is defined (which is a moderately intricate operation); thereafter, you're not supposed to try modifying the storage (via the name `temp`).  If you want to modify the storage, don't use `const`.  If you try to modify the storage, the compiler will complain (I assume you wouldn't be asking if it didn't complain), and you invoke _undefined behaviour_ which is always A Bad Thing!™

Comment: `struct_B b = {A1}; struct_C c = {&b}; const struct_D temp = {&c};`

Comment: @Tiến Nguyễn Not sure if this would be off-topic but why would you ever need such nested structure. Since struct_B and struct_C have pointers any change in B.G would automatically change value in `temp.E->F->G`. Unless this a curiosity/learning-phase/homework question I see no reason to use `const` keyword here.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to set value to `const` structure is to initialize it while declaring it. So,the solution would be:

```
struct_B B = {A1}; 
struct_C C = {&B};  
struct_D temp = {&C};
```

However, I haven't come across any scenario where such nested `const` structures would be required.

Answer (score 0):

At first: If we see something qualified as `const` we should take it seriously and avoid to cast away the constness. If you cast away the const qualifier of global or static data then you get undefined behavior and you are going to get a segmentation fault in linux.

In general, the correct way is the one pointed by Suven Pandey in the other answer.

However, there are valid cases to cast away const. Your case may qualify as as one of the exceptions in https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP05-C.+Do+not+cast+away+a+const+qualification

> EXP05-C-EX3: Because const means "read-only," and not "constant," it is sometimes useful to declare struct members as (pointer to) const objects to obtain diagnostics when the user tries to change them in some way other than via the functions that are specifically designed to maintain that data type. Within those functions, however, it may be necessary to strip off the const qualification to update those members.

We can cast away const when your data is in a mutable region of memory like the stack or heap. We need to be careful, anyway, as that is likely to produce unexpected behavior if the code relays on that data being immutable and we change it.

So, this is what you asked for:

```
typedef enum {A1, A2} enum_A;
typedef struct { const enum_A G; } struct_B;
typedef struct { const struct_B * F; } struct_C;
typedef struct { const struct_C *E; } struct_D;

int main() {
   const struct_B b = {A1};
   const struct_C c = {&b}; 
   const struct_D temp = {&c};
   enum_A *pointer_to_non_const_A = &temp.E[0].F[0].G;
   *pointer_to_non_const_A = A2;
}
```

But that depends on where `temp` is defined and is going to cause compilation warning. If `temp` is a global that is going to crash. Here are the cases when it works, but shall not be used, and when it crashes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

const int global_in_data_segment = 0;

int main() {
    const int in_stack = 0;
    static const int static_in_data_segment = 0;
    const int *in_heap = malloc(sizeof(int));

    int *works;
    works = &in_stack; *works = 1;
    works = in_heap; *works = 2;

    int *crashes;
    crashes = &global_in_data_segment; *crashes = 3;
    crashes = &static_in_data_segment; *crashes = 4;
}
```

For completeness, c++ has const_cast: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast